# Ressources for Windows forensic analysis?

Tags: windows, forensics

I am looking for a free handbook (Beginner-Intermediate level) to delve into Windows forensic analysis with a specific focus on malware discovery. I haven't found anything which can get me started, does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: Unfortunately, requests for books, guides, etc are off topic because they go stale so quickly. You can hop over to the DMZ chat room to ask these types of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think ["Malware Forensics Investigating and Analyzing Malicious Code"](http://download.adamas.ai/dlbase/ebooks/VX_related/Malware%20Forensics%20Investigating%20and%20Analyzing%20Malicious%20Code.pdf) would be a good place to start.

I'd highly recommend Russinovich's tools you can download [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062)

Also, there are some practical challenges online to get you started [here](https://honeynet.org/challenges)
 and [here](https://digital-forensics.sans.org/blog/2011/08/10/malware-analysis-challenge-to-strengthen-your-skills)